# Consecutive group with size K in an array

Tags: java, arrays, treeset, sliding-window

I was asked this question in an onsite interview recently. I still cannot come up with a solution.

**Question:** 
There is a garden with N slots. In each slot, there is a flower. The N flowers will bloom one by one in N days. In each day, there will be exactly one flower blooming and it will be in the status of blooming since then.

Given an array named flowers consist of numbers from 1 to N. Each number in the array represents the place where the flower will open in that day.

For example, **flowers[i] = x** means that the unique flower that blooms at day **i** will be at position **x**, where **i** and **x** will be in the range from 1 to N.

Given K, find the **last** day on which there is at least one group of bloomed flowers of size K. Return -1 if no such day is found

**Example :**
array : [3,1,5,4,2] ;  k = 1
day1 ：0 0 1 0 0 
day2 ：1 0 1 0 0 
day3 ：1 0 1 0 1 
day4 ：1 0 1 1 1 >>> Last day on which you can see a group of size k=1
day5 ：1 1 1 1 1

The answer is day 4 (flower: 1).

If k = 2 or 4 
The answer is -1.

If k = 3 
The answer is day 4 (flowers : 3,4,5).

If k = 5 
The answer is day 5 (flowers : 1,2,3,4,5).

**Edit 1:**
I was able to solve it in O(n^2). But the interviewer was expecting O(nlogn) complexity

For those who use leetcode, this is a variation of the following question : https://leetcode.com/problems/k-empty-slots/description/ (can only access with leetcode paid subscription)

Thanks!!

Comment: "find the last day on which there is at least one group of blossoming flowers of size K" contradicts with: "In each day, there will be exactly one flower blooming"

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. If you make an attempt at solving it yourself and get stuck on a particular part of your attempt, feel free to ask here again. But "I want this thing, somebody write it for me" is not appropriate for this forum.

Comment: Are you looking for the algorithm (i.e. you want to code it)?  Or working code?

Comment: @alfasin      Once the flower bloomed the flower will be in bloomed state from that point onwards as in line 3 "In each day, there will be exactly one flower blooming and it will be in the status of blooming since then." hope this clears.

Comment: @mypetlion My apologies for not clearly stating my intentions. Just to be clear I do not want the code. I was able to solve in O(n*n) (applying sliding window after each flower bloomed). But interviewer wanted an algorithm with O(nlogn) time complexity. So I was wondering if there is any better way to solve this in nlogn using some data structure.

Comment: @IanMc I am not looking for a working code. Just some help to approach this problem. I know it can be done in O(n*n) complexity (applying sliding window after each flower bloomed). But interviewer was looking for O(nlogn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved in O(nlogn) by implementing Union-Find (with Union by Rank and path compression).

Initially (at day=0), each flower slot represents a distinct set
of size=0.  There will be N such sets at this time.
The variable `k-sets` represents how many sets have a size of exactly `k`.  This is initialized to zero.  The variable `answer` represents the last iteration (day) which has at least one set of size `k`; and is initialized to `-1`;

Processing the array (N iterations):  When a flower blooms, the following events occur at slot `index`:

1. The size of the set at position `index` now has a size of 1.  If `k==1` then `k-sets` increases by 1
2. Union Right (set at `index+1`):  If you are not at position `N` (i.e. you can't union right at the boundary position `N`) then call `UNION(index, index+1)`.  The union will only occur if the set size at `index+1` is greater than zero.
3. Union Left (set at `index-1`):  If you are not at position 0, then call `UNION(index, index-1)`.  Again, a union only occurs if the left set is not empty.
4. If `k-sets` > 0, then `answer = day` (i.e. where day is the `n-th` iteration of the array)

When a union occurs (call them `A` and `B`), three updates concerning `k-sets` must be done:

1. If the size of `A` is `k`, then `k-sets--`
2. If the size of `B` is `k`, then `k-sets--`
3. If the size of the union of A, B is `k`, then `k-sets++`

At the end of the iteration, `print answer`

Runtime:  There are `N` days, and the cost of each day is linear with O(logn), so the run time is `O(NlogN)`

[Proof of O(logn) time of Union-Find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_O(log*n)_time_complexity_of_union%E2%80%93find)